# The type or namespace name 'ContractClassFor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit

I am using the following code.

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IWindow))]
```

Why the error "The type or namespace name 'ContractClassFor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" is coming?

Comment: did you add System.Diagnostics.Contracts namespace?

Comment: Yes. I added System.Diagnostics.Contracts namespace.

Comment: please try to add mscorlib.dll to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happened because of an ambiguity issue. I removed Microsoft.Contracts from reference. Now its working fine. Thanks Mr.Frebin Francis for your support.